# How to create a one time link on Django for video file

Tags: django

I need to create a one time link on Django for my videos from theft. 
Please can you give me an example of how this can be done.

Comment: Define "one time". Do you want it to be only accessible once? Time out after a number of days? Only allow one download?

Comment: You can use `random` function for that.

Comment: Time out after a number of hours for video online

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a one time single use link system which I built just now. You can adapt it to use time by adding that to Models and checking for it in the view.

**models.py**

```
class OneTimeLinkModel(models.Model):
    one_time_code = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    #expiry_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
    #You would need an expiry time for the time based method
```

`one_time_code` identifies the particular code used to access that item
`expiry_time` would be when the link is supposed to time out

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('generate_link', views.generate_link, name='generate_link'),
    path('one_time_link/<str:access_code>', views.one_time_link, name='one_time_link'),
]
```

`generate_link` creates the one time link. You can do whatever you want with the link once you have it, whether it be email it or just present it to the user.

`one_time_link` is the url for the single use link itself.

**views.py**

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import OneTimeLinkModel
import random
import string

#generates the string of the one time URL
def randomString(stringLength=20):
    """Generate a random string of fixed length """
    letters = string.ascii_lowercase
    return ''.join(random.choice(letters) for i in range(stringLength))

#generates the link itself
def generate_link(request):
    the_string = randomString(stringLength=20)
    OneTimeLinkModel.objects.create(one_time_code=the_string)
    return HttpResponse('<a href="/polls/one_time_link/{}">{}{}</a>'.format(the_string, request.build_absolute_uri(), the_string))


#handles the link request
def one_time_link(request,access_code=0):

    if (access_code == 0):
        return HttpResponse("Test link")

    elif OneTimeLinkModel.objects.filter(one_time_code=access_code).exists() and (insert your time check here):

        #remove the line below if you do not want the link to self destruct after it has been used
        OneTimeLinkModel.objects.filter(one_time_code=access_code).delete()
        return HttpResponse("Hey, your linked worked. Make sure to download as it won't work again.")

    elif not OneTimeLinkModel.objects.filter(one_time_code=access_code).exists():
        return HttpResponse("Bad or expired link.")
    else:
        return HttpResponse("Bad or expired link.")
```